# Searching in Database and showing in react table

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code in PHP which has path "http://localhost:80/ico/vypsani.php"

```
    $ico = $_POST['ico'];
    include_once("core.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ico WHERE ico = '$ico'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $json_array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         $json_array[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($json_array);
```

in PHP I am searching row in database with input in React and its working, but I need to ge it into this table

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Data = () =>{
    const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch("http://localhost:80/ico/vypsani.php")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                setItem(result);
            }
         )
    },[])
    return (
        <div className="row">
                <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
                    <thead className='thead-dark'>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">IČO</th>
                    <th scope="col">Název</th>
                    <th scope="col">Město</th>
                    <th scope="col">Ulice</th>
                    <th scope="col">Číslo Domovní</th>
                    <th scope="col">Číslo Orientační</th>
                    <th scope="col">Datum uložení</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            item.map(item=>(
                                <tr key={item.ID}>
                                    <td>{item.ID}</td>
                                    <td>{item.ico}</td>
                                    <td>{item.nazev}</td>
                                    <td>{item.mesto}</td>
                                    <td>{item.ulice}</td>
                                    <td>{item.cisloDomovni}</td>
                                    <td>{item.cisloOrientacni}</td>
                                    <td>{item.datum}</td>
                                </tr>
                            ))
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

but it shows the row from database like this [image] and not in react table, I think because of the POST.

How react app looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Data from "./data/data.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form action='http://localhost:80/ico/vypsani.php' method="post">
        <div className='form'>
        <h1>IČO</h1>
        <input name="ico" onKeyPress={(event) => {
          if (!/[0-9]/.test(event.key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Zadávat lze pouze čísla")
          }
        }}
    />
        <h1>Název firmy</h1>
        <input name="nazev" type="text"></input>
        <br></br>
        <button type="submit" name='submit' value="vyhledat">Vyhledat</button>
        <br></br>
        <button type="submit" name='submit' value="odeslat">Odeslat</button>
        <br></br>
        </div>
        <h1>Výpis z Databáze</h1>
        <Data/>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: your question is not clear please add detail what you want ???

Comment: basically this code is working, but `$ico = $_POST['ico'];`, in this variable is number from input and when i use it  like this it shows me row from database in php file and not in react table (the image in question), but when i set `$ico` directlly number that i used in input, its showing it in react table like i want, but i need get that number from input, i think its because of POST

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 0):

**Change your useEffect like this**

```
useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("http://localhost:80/ico/vypsani.php")
    .then(result => {
            setItem(result);
            console.log(result);
        }
     )
     .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
},[])
```

**and table body like this**

```
<tbody>
    {
       item && item?.map(ele=>(
            <tr key={ele.ID}>
                <td>{ele.ID}</td>
                <td>{ele.ico}</td>
                <td>{ele.nazev}</td>
                <td>{ele.mesto}</td>
                <td>{ele.ulice}</td>
                <td>{ele.cisloDomovni}</td>
                <td>{ele.cisloOrientacni}</td>
                <td>{ele.datum}</td>
            </tr>
        ))
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: thank you, but its doing same thing, still showing in http://localhost:80/ico/vypsani.php

Comment: your question is that you want to  get data based on  text box input ???

Answer (score 0):

POSTing form to php page is not the correct way to do this. Please read answer to this question: [Send a ReactJS form to a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564391/send-a-reactjs-form-to-a-php-page)

To get your code to work, you can remove form in the html and handle the request using fetch only.
Also, change $ico = $_POST['ico']; to $ico = $_GET['ico']; in your php file

```
  import React from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      tableData: [],
      ico: ''
    };
  }

  handleInput = event => {
    this.setState({ ico: event.target.value });
  };

  logValue = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:80/ico/vypsani.php?ico=" + this.state.ico)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState(state => state.tableData = result);
      }
    )
    .catch(err => {
      throw err
    });
  }; 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className='form'>
          <h1>IČO</h1>
          <input name="ico" onKeyPress={(event) => {
            if (!/[0-9]/.test(event.key)) {
              event.preventDefault();
              alert("Zadávat lze pouze čísla")
            }
          }}
          />
          <h1>Název firmy</h1>
          <input name="nazev" onChange={this.handleInput} type="text"></input>
          <br></br>

          <button type="submit" name='submit' onClick={this.logValue} value="vyhledat">Vyhledat</button>
          <br></br>
          <button type="submit" name='submit' value="odeslat">Odeslat</button>
          <br></br>
        </div>
        <h1>Výpis z Databáze</h1>
        <div  >
          <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
            <thead className='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">IČO</th>
                <th scope="col">Název</th>
                <th scope="col">Město</th>
                <th scope="col">Ulice</th>
                <th scope="col">Číslo Domovní</th>
                <th scope="col">Číslo Orientační</th>
                <th scope="col">Datum uložení</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {
                this.state.tableData.map(item => (
                  <tr key={item.ID}>
                    <td>{item.ID}</td>
                    <td>{item.ico}</td>
                    <td>{item.nazev}</td>
                    <td>{item.mesto}</td>
                    <td>{item.ulice}</td>
                    <td>{item.cisloDomovni}</td>
                    <td>{item.cisloOrientacni}</td>
                    <td>{item.datum}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>

    );
  }
}
export default Test;
```